# HTML clickable image has to resize font

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am building a website and I am trying something I cant figure out how it has to work.

In my menu I have 2 images.

```
 <li id="fontup"><img width="40" height="40" src="images/fontup.png"/></li>
 <li id="fontdown"><img width="40" height="40" src="images/fontdownpng.png"/></li>
```

Those 2 images represent a button in my menu that if you click it, the font size on the website has to increment or decrement by 1. I know HTML support the option "smaller" and "bigger".
When I click the one image -> a JavaScript or jQuery has to run to resize the font. 
How exactly do I do this? (I am a very beginner in HTML and dreamweaver)

At the moment I have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("fontup").onclick = function() {
  var listValue = selectTag.options[selectTag.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("font").style.fontSize = larger;
  };
  };
</script>
```

As you can see I have this from a tutorial on the website, but I dont know what I need to customize more to have this working? 
Also I have set a p-element with an id="font" to test this out but obviously this doesnt work.

** update : 
Code I have now is :

On my index.html =

The scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FontsSize.js"></script>
```

My 2 buttons

```
<li> <button id="fontup"><img width="40" height="40"    src="images/fontup.png"/>  </button></li>
<li> <button id="fontdown"><img width="40" height="40" src="images/fontdownpng.png"/> </button></li>
```

For testing I also have this:

```
<div id="test">lorem ipsum etc</div>
```

In a seperate .js file I have the following code:

```
var fs = 23;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test').css('font-size', fs);
});

 $("#fontup").click(function() {
fs++
$("#test").css('font-size', fs);
});

$("#fontdown").click(function() {
fs--
$("#test").css('font-size', fs);
});
```

How come this still doesnt work?
If I update var fs the size does change... but if I click the button.. it doesnt.

Comment: Not yet related to your current question, but you will stumble across it very soon: keep in mind to use relative units `em`, `rem` or `%` on other `font-size`s declarations if you want a change in font-size on the body element to affect the other elements.

Comment: Another question, how you do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use jquery (as mentioned in your question), this will do what you want.  You start by setting a default size for page load, then reset the font size (up or down) each time a button is clicked.  The code below applies the re-sizing to a `div`, but you could apply it to `body` if you want to change the size of the font on everything (except elements with a more specific font size declaration)

```js
var fs = 23;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').css('font-size', fs);

  $('#fontUp').click(function() {
    fs++
    $('#content').css('font-size', fs);
  });

  $('#fontDown').click(function() {
    fs--
    $('#content').css('font-size', fs);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fontUp">UP</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="fontDown">DOWN</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="content">lorem ipsum etc</div>
```

EDIT:  code updated for external JS file

Comment: Where do I put the code above? I have tried to make a .js file and then run a script with that code. I have made the 2 images now have a button function. I have put the div content on the site for testing, but it doesnt seem to work :/. So where do I best put the code you have above? Greetings

Comment: If I change var fs I can see it changes. But if I click the button it doesnt seem to change size. even though I use the same ID as the buttons.

Comment: Can you post a URL?  Make sure you are loading jquery.  Have you checked your console? If you are not running jquery, you will get an error message `$ is not defined`.

Comment: its not online yet, I still have it on dreamweaver. You want me to host it already, that would be no problem? Kind regards

Comment: It's up to you - it's not possible to guess what's going wrong without being able to see the code.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I am using now. I hope this helps out a bit. Kind regards

Comment: I think the issue is that your external JS is loaded before DOM ready, so the click functions are not bound to the button elements.  Try putting everything inside `$(document)ready` - just delete the first `});` and add it to the very end.  I've updated the code above to do this.

Comment: Yes it works now!! thank you verry much!! Anny idea how I write this in JavaScript? (either do it works perfectly on jQuery)